# Firebase Remote Config setDefaults: doesn't store NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-remote-config

It looks like `setDefaults:` does't parse and store a nested NSDictionary object correctly.

This is some simple test code:

```
FIRRemoteConfig *remoteConfig = [FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig];

NSDictionary *defaultValues = @{
    @"stringTestKey": @"stringValue",
    @"numberTestKey": @10,
    @"dictionaryTestKey": @{
            @"nestedKey":@"nestedValue"
    }
};

NSLog(@"default dict > %@", defaultValues);

[remoteConfig setDefaults:defaultValues];

NSString *stringTest = [remoteConfig defaultValueForKey:@"stringTestKey"].stringValue;
NSNumber *numberTest = [remoteConfig defaultValueForKey:@"numberTestKey"].numberValue;
NSDictionary *dictionaryTest = [remoteConfig defaultValueForKey:@"dictionaryTestKey"].JSONValue;

NSLog(@"String value > %@", stringTest);
NSLog(@"Number value > %@", numberTest);
NSLog(@"Dictionary value > %@", dictionaryTest);
```

The first two `NSLog` correctly return `stringValue` and `10` however the third one simply return `null`.

Am I doing something wrong or the current SDK is broken?

Comment: What are you expecting it to log, and why?

Comment: I commented below the code example: the third NSLog should return an NSDictionary which is the value of `dictionaryTestKey`. Instead it returns `(null)`.

Comment: I tested the same behaviour also in the Objective-C demo project provided with Firebase documentation: when a new key with a dictionary value type is added to the plist included in the demo, `defaultValueForKey` for that key returns `(null)`.

Comment: If I read the documentation correctly, JSONValue will parse the value of the config field as JSON.  That means it's probably expecting a string as input, which is how you represent JSON.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you use JSONValue, stringValue, dataValue... etc... the value returned is always `(null)` when the default is of type NSDictionary. Also, `NSArray *defaultKeys = [self.remoteConfig allKeysFromSource:FIRRemoteConfigSourceDefault];` doesn't returns any key when the value type associated is a dictionary. This indicates that at some point `setDefaults:` fails to correctly encode and store dictionary types to the extreme that not even the key associated to it gets saved.

Comment: If you think there's an error, then please file a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: Yep. I did report a bug here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs - I wasn't yet sure when I posted here on StackOverflow, mainly because I'm relatively new to the Firebase Remote Config SDK so I wanted to make sure that I didn't miss something. But after further testing I reached the conclusion that this is an actual bug in the SDK and filed a bug report. I'm fairly confident... but at the same time I'm really surprised no one came across this issue before.

Comment: Just to confirm, what is this `.JSONValue;`

Comment: @jay https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/RemoteConfigValue

Comment: Thanks - just wanted to clarify you're using the firebase function and not a third party library. Have you tried using  remoteConfig [configValueForKey](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/FIRRemoteConfig#-configvalueforkey:)? instead of `defaultValueForKey`?

Comment: Yep, same behaviour. And even if it worked, yes it could have been a workaround... but it would not change the fact that there's a bug in the SDK that needs to be fixed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have found solution, but I encountered the same issue now, after some times digging, it turns out you need to save it as `String` type instead of `Dictionary`, I use plist file to get the default value, just add new key `dictionaryTestKey`, and set type as `String`, set value as something like

`{
  “url”: "https://google.com”,
  "nestedKey": "nestedValue"
}`

then use `setDefaults` to save defaults,
when you need retrieve it, use

`let data = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: "dictionaryTestKey").dataValue
let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(YourDecodableStruct.self, from: data)`

you will get all the info you want.